# Synonym for a Sequence in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, sequence, synonym

I want to create a synonym for a sequence in oracle and fetch `currval` from it.

I created a synonym using this statement.

```
CREATE SYNONYM NUMGEN FOR MY_SEQ;
```

when I fetch the `currval` or `extval` from `NUMGEN` it generate error, synonym doesn't exist.

```
SELECT NUMGEN.currval FROM dual;
```

Can anyone help me to fetch `currval` from synonym.

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us. This does work. See the example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/883cb/1

Comment: currval doesn't work neither in your example.

Comment: In my database even nextval isn't working, i don't understand why. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Both are working now, but i dont understand why i have execute nextval before executing currval.

Comment: You **have** to call `nextval` before you can call `currval`. This is clearly documented in the manual.

Comment: [this link explains how to do this](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1675349-How-to-access-the-Sequence-created-in-other-Schema)

Answer (score 1):

You might have not given the privileges to the user.
Try giving privilege using either of following query and try.

`GRANT SELECT ANY SEQUENCE to NEWDB;`

`GRANT SELECT ON ORIGINALDB.SEQUENCENAME TO NEWDB;`